# How do your make GUI elements and images not flicker around?

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm making a UWP application, but it doesn't render GUI elements smoothly like iPad and iOS, or other native toolkits. When you navigate pages, images set in xaml flicker. When resizing the page, GUI elements jump then settle to their desired spot. Whats up with this? I'm running a beefy computer. Whats the deal? What tricks are there to eliminate these graphical artifacts in UWP development?

Comment: UWP really isn't the best for this kind of thing.

Comment: Everything is possible with some effort. To prevent images from flickering you can introduce animations or only load page when images are loaded. You can cache images, resize them upfront so that runtime doesn't have to. GUI elements can be animated manually when window is resizing. This all requires some experience, of course. What I defensively wouldn't do is listen to web developers about what UWP is best at and at what it isn't.